# In-app billing notifications. How to do it?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, push-notification, in-app-billing

I've been looking for the in-app billing's offical sample app from Android Developers and I don't understand how can I change a notification's title. I mean, how do am I suppose to alert the user when a purchase has been cancelled or even successful?

I know that a notification is sent to the notifications bar but I don't really understand how to change its title, action, etc. Does anyone know where I can do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show a custom Notification then you need to send your own notification. You can't modify the one that Google Play shows.

The docs tell you that, as a best practise, you should show a notification (on purchases etc) to the user that when clicked will open an activity in your app that shows the status of the users purchase. Then they go and throw up their own notification that when clicked goes to your main activity AND there is no way to suppress said Notification, so if you do use your own notification the user gets 2 notifications for cancellations/refunds.

So you either just leave their notification (I'm not a fan of this option because their notification only shows for refunds/cancellations and not purchases and links to the wrong activity) or you show your own notifications (as well as the Google Play notifications appearing) for everything - more consistent, better looking, you can set a more appropriate message and title AND you can make the notification link to a more appropriate activity within your application.

I think the second option is better but the Google Play Notifications still bug me.